# Barking up the wrong tree

Tags: riddle

> When I live, I am green,
>   When I die, I am brown,
>   When I am hurt, I am black.
>
> I am soft when I’m alive,
>   Hard when I’m not.

What am I?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.se! Take time to familiarize yourself with this site!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it:

> a tree?

Because:

> When it is living, it is soft and green, when it dies, it is brown and hard. When it is burnt, it goes black

Comment: Wow you did it! You are really good!